# jQuery toggle button opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, effects

I am trying to toggle two buttons's opacity when the user hovers over the containing div, and when they mouse out it should go back to being hidden, at the moment it is doing that but as soon as I try to click on one of the buttons, it goes mad and starts toggling the opacity on and off repeatedly, here is my code,

Javascript/jQuery:

```
    $('#container').live({
      mouseover: function() {
          $('.button').fadeToggle();
      },
      mouseout: function() {
          $('.button').fadeToggle();
      }
    });
```

HTML:

```
            <div id="container">
                <div class="button"></div>
                <div></div>
                <div class="button"></div>
            </div>
```

Thanx in advance!

PS: Sorry about the title, I forgot to change it, as it is showing and hiding the buttons with a fade effect and not toggling the opacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mouseover` and `mouseout` events bubble, meaning that they will also fire for all of the element's children.

You should handle `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, which do not bubble.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! One last thing though, at the moment if I go over the `#container` div a few times quickly, it will toggle the buttons visibility the amount of times I went over the container, which makes sense since it takes time for the animation to complete, but is there a way to make it stop doing that? Isn't it called event stacking? Please excuse my ignorance, I'm still learning. :)

Comment: @user: Call `.stop().fadeToggle()`.

Comment: Tried that already, it just kind of fades out a little more each time I go over it until it's not visible anymore. But thanx anyways, I'll play with it a little more.

Comment: This seemed to have done the trick `.stop(true, true).fadeToggle();` Thanx for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

.stop() your animation before running it again.

```
$('#container').live({
  mouseover: function() {
      $('.button').stop();
      $('.button').fadeToggle();
  },
  mouseout: function() {
      $('.button').stop();
      $('.button').fadeToggle();
  }
});
```